# Why is this start_pos invalid?

Tags: python, pygame

Why does this code not work?

```
def grid(vl):
    vl_var = screen.get_width() / vl
    i = 1
    while True:
        if i == vl:
            i = 1
            break
        else:
            pygame.draw.line(screen, (94, 94, 94), vl_var * i, vl_var * i * screen.get_width())
            i += 1
```

When executing this program, i get the following error

```
TypeError: invalid start_pos argument
```

I have no idea why this would be invalid...

Comment: If you take some time to read [the `pygame.draw.line` documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line), what does it say about the arguments, especially `start_pos`?

Comment: the `start_pos` and `end_pos` values you have provided are both just numbers, but you need to provide `(x, y)` coordinates for each position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw a line you need to specify the start and end position. A position is a tuple with a *x* and *y* coordinate. [`pygame.draw.line`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.line) draws a line from a start and end position specified in the third and fourth parameters. e.g.:

```py
def grid(vl, hl):
    width, height = screen.get_size()
    vl_var = width // vl
    hl_var = height // hl
    # vertical lines
    for i in range(vl+1):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (94, 94, 94), (vl_var*i, 0), (vl_var*i, height))
    # horiontal lines
    for i in range(hl+1):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (94, 94, 94), (0, hl_var*i), (width, hl_var*i))
```